# Angularjs directive private scope/model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've got an issue with a directive that is becoming a pain to resolve, which appears to be from a change in angular between version 1.0.8 and version 1.2.0.

In the [first jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdmnzv1d/) using version 1.0.8 you can see that upon changing an input file the `fileChanged` fn is called and the `$scope.file` is changed.

Yet in the [second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7w0r7pr/) using version 1.2.0, the same code just doesn't update the directive

It looks like it has something to do with the a directive having an isolate scope, but not being able to have it's own scope variables. For instance, the controller of a directive:

```
controller: function ($scope, $timeout, $upload) {
     $scope.fileCount = 0;
}
```

Am I missing something pretty key here?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is due to no template being set for the directive:

```
...
scope: {
        uploadPath: '@'
},
templateUrl: 'file-uploader.html',
controller: function ($scope, $timeout, $upload)
...
```

I'm sure using `template: 'html here'` would also work, but the reality is there much more html.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abfkL5ro/)

Answer (score 0):

There was a change with regard to isolated scopes. The expression `$scope.file = element.files[0];` changes `file` in the directive's scope, not the scope outside. What you need to do is to establish a connection between `file` in the directive and `file` outside of it.

```
<div file-upload file="file">
  <input type="file" />
  <hr />
  File selected: {{file.name}}
</div>

...

myApp.directive('fileUpload', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        file: '='
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves the issue also, but it would then mean any consumer of file-upload would have to be aware of how the directive works, which in this case is undesirable.

Comment: @danrichardson In your original example the developer needs to know that an `input[type=file]` is necessary, that's true.  But that was also true before you migrated ;) Your answer is definitely the better alternative but does not solve the original problem: Sharing data between isolated scopes and the outside world.

Comment: It wasn't a migration issue, I was trying to troubleshoot where the issue was by trying it with a version earlier than 1.2 (if it worked). Again though, I'm not sharing data between isolated scopes, it's a directive that adds one way functionality. Anyway, again thank you :)